# Adding .dll for Lazy Loading in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor WASM and was trying to lazy load my own component, from the same project. Therefore, I have created my `.csproj` like this

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AssemblyName>Parama.LicenseMaster.BCUI</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Parama.LicenseMaster.BCUI</RootNamespace>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Parama.LicenseMaster.BCUI.dll"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

when building the application there is no error occured, but when I ran the application, I received a runtime error that stated `Error: Could not find assembly: Parama.LicenseMaster.BCUI`

[image: Runtime Error]

I read the docs from Microsoft and followed the exact same way as the docs told. Am I missing something to use this Lazy Load feature?